# Find a value and copy multiple values after an offset from 2 workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, find, multiple-columns, copy-paste

I am having some trouble getting this to work. I've tried a couple different methods of doing this but I'm coming up empty.

I want to take a **value** in one workbook, and find it in a column in **another workbook** and then do an offset and **copy 6 columns** of information (1 row, six columns, so 6 values) and paste them back into the original workbook.

I got the below code from a *similar* question but it's just bringing back a huge column of bordered cells... rather confused about that one. This code is just me trying to find the value, go 19 columns over, copy that value, and bring it back to the first workbook. Eventually I'd like to grab the aforementioned 6 values...

```
Sub findgage()
Dim gage As String

gage = Worksheets("Caliper").Range("C4").Value

With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="[path]\IMTECOPY.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)


    With .Worksheets("All").Range("B1:B1000")
      .AutoFilter 1, gage
      Range("S" & ActiveCell.Row & ":X" & ActiveCell.Row).Select


    End With

End With
End Sub
```

**UPDATE** Alright so the above code is doing *almost* exactly what I want it to do but it's selecting the 6 cells the row below the "active row". What am I missing here? I don't see anything that's making it do this...

Here's a picture of what it's selecting:

[image]

Any idea why it's jumping down?

Comment: 1. If *gage* is in C4, why are you pasting results into J15? 2. Does .offset(1, 19) mean start at the 19th column (column S) or the 19th column to the right of column B (column U)?

Comment: Can you please post your (sample) data in your question. That way we can understand what you are looking at

Comment: This would make more sense if you posted a sample of what you're working with and what you're trying to do (perhaps a screenshot?).  Part of the issue is, you're basing your question (and a very method to solution) on what *you* think Excel is capable of  There's many ways to accomplish any task in Excel, and you seem stuck on only one, which is probably not the best way. For example, why **19**?  What's there?  Is there a column heading or something else to look for better than "19 over"? And what happens if the spreadsheet changes? What kind of data are you copying? What about linking cells?

Comment: C4 is a cell that the user types in a value. I want the code to look for that value in another workbook, and when it finds it, go to the right 19 columns and copy the next 6 values, then bring them back to the original workbook. J15 is just a random cell that I want the data to go into.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub findgage()
    Dim gage As String

    gage = Worksheets("Caliper").Range("C4").Value

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="[path]\IMTECOPY.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
        With .Worksheets("All").Range("B1:B1000")
          .AutoFilter 1, gage
          Worksheets("Caliper").Range("J15").Resize(, 6).Value = .Offset(1).Resize(, 6).Value
          .AutoFilter
        End With
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Finally. With a lot of bits and pieces.

```
Sub findgage()
    Dim gage As String

    gage = Worksheets("Caliper").Range("C4").Value

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="[path]\IMTECOPY.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)
   ' Dim myrange As String

        With .Worksheets("All").Range("$B:$B")
          .AutoFilter 1, gage

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible). 
_Cells(1, 2).Select
        thisrow = ActiveCell.Row

dataset = Range("S" & thisrow & ":X" & thisrow).Value

Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Caliper").Range("G14:L14") = dataset
Workbooks("IMTECOPY.xlsx").Close False



    End With

End With
End Sub
```

This opens the log, filters it to the gage number we're looking for, selects the values in the 6 columns we need to look at, and brings them back to the original workbook. I sincerely hope some of this helps someone else, because this was a silly amount of work and frustration.